# Remove item from observablecollection

Tags: vb.net, linq

I'm struggling to figure out how to remove and add to an `observableCollection` in the following scenario:

```
    Dim flightsColl As New ObservableCollection(Of Flight)
    Dim f1 As Flight = New Flight With {.FlightName = "Jet1"}
    Dim f2 As Flight = New Flight With {.FlightName = "Boeing"}

    Dim p1 As Passenger = New Passenger() With {.Name = "Tim", .Address = "address1"}
    Dim p2 As Passenger = New Passenger() With {.Name = "Tom", .Address = "address2"}
    Dim p3 As Passenger = New Passenger() With {.Name = "Tas", .Address = "address3"}

    'add 2 passangers to Jet1

    f1.Passengers.Add(p1)
    f1.Passengers.Add(p2)

    'add passnger3 to boeing
    f2.Passengers.Add(p3)

    'add flight1 & 2 to flight list
    flightsColl.Add(f1)
    flightsColl.Add(f2)
```

in the above eg, I have a flightsColl which is an observablecollection.
as you can see it has 2 flights , the 1st one has 2 passengers and the second one has 1
passenger

Now if I have to move passenger 2(p2) to flight 2 then
from `flightsColl` I have to
`Remove Passenger 2 from flight 1`

`Add Passenger 2 to flight 2`

**Update**

```
Public Class Flight

Public Property Name() As String
Public Property Passengers As ICollection(Of Passenger)


Public Sub New()
    Me.Appliances = New ObservableCollection(Of Passenger)
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: `f1.RemoveItem(p2)` and `f2.Add(p2)` will do exactly that, but I don't think that's what you actually want.

Comment: One thing to be aware of is that adding and removing passengers from flights won't cause any notifications that ``flightsColl`` has been updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you have to go through flightsColl ? You have a reference to both the flights and the passengers.

```
f1.Passengers.Remove(p2)
```

... etc

** Update **

```
Dim oldflight As Flight = flightsColl.FirstOrDefault(Function(f) f.FlightName = "oldFlightName")
Dim passenger As Passenger = oldflight.Passengers.FirstOrDefault(Function(p) p.Name = "passengerName")
oldflight.Passengers.Remove(passenger)

Dim newflight As Flight = flightsColl.FirstOrDefault(Function(f) f.FlightName = "newFlightName")
newflight.Passengers.Add(passenger)
```

Does that help? You'd need to add some error checking in there (and SingleOrDefault would be better if you don't want to accidentally remove a different passenger with the same name)

Comment: @nickvane I'm trying to simulate my scenario with above sample, my function receives flightsColl, passenger name ,previous flight Name and new flight name and I have to move the passenger as mentioned above, hope this makes sense!

Comment: I had "Collection was of a fixed size" error on `oldflight.Passengers.Remove(passenger)` I think thats because Passengers is an ICollection in Flight class - please see my update above - and the constructor does not get called due to wcf datacontract serialization. but in a simple scenario with a form and a button with those 2 classes it works fine.

Comment: I'm accepting this as the answer because it does exactly what I wanted given my example above, I still have to figure out how to remove from ICollection in my application. any suggestions will be welcome!! Thanks

Comment: Could you use the `[OnDeserializing]` attribute to define a method which creates the type of collection you need (i.e. one that supports removal). Or, depending on how you're creating your WCF contracts, put this logic inside a constructtor in a partial class?